# PHP: Display message at specific day and time

Tags: php, date, time, message

I'm trying to make a script to display specific messages at specific day and time. I've got the script working to display at a specific day and at a specific time, but not the two combined.

**How can I make the script display a specific message at mondays between 3pm and 4pm?**

Look at the script I made so far;

```
<?php
//Messages
$afternoon = "It's afternoon";
$evening = "It's evening";
$night = "It's night.";
$morning = "It's morning!";
$friday = "Soon weekend!";

//Get time
$current_time = date(G);
//Get day
$current_day = date(l);

//12PM - 4PM
if ($current_time >= 12 && $current_time <= 16) {
echo $afternoon;
}
//5PM - 11PM
elseif ($current_time >= 17 && $current_time <= 24) {
echo $evening;
}
//00AM - 05AM
elseif ($current_time >= 1 && $current_time <= 5) {
echo $night;
}
//6AM - 11AM
elseif ($current_time >= 6 && $current_time <= 11) {
echo $morning;
}

//Friday, display message
if ($current_day == "Friday") {
echo $friday;
}
?>
```

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with PHP? Since your day and time will be depended on the server and not the timezone of the user.

Comment: Good point! But yeah, in this case I want to display it according to the server and not the timezone of the user :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($current_day == "Monday") {
    if ($current_time >= 15 && $current_time <= 16) {
        echo "It's Monday and the time is between 3PM and 4PM.";
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question, @Stark. I trying to display a message from 10AM to 2PM, and then from 2PM to 6PM. If I use this code, it displays both of the messages between 2:00pm and 2:59pm. How can I solve this? :)

`if ($current_day == "Monday") {
    if ($current_time >= 10 && $current_time <= 14) {
        echo "Monday between 10AM and 2PM";
    }
}
if ($current_day == "Monday") {
    if ($current_time >= 14 && $current_time <= 18) {
        echo "Monday between 2PM and 6PM.";
    }
}`

Answer (score 3):

```
if($current_day == "Monday" && $current_time >= 3 && $current_time <= 4){
   //Monday text
}
```

Comment: So if I want to display a message between 3AM and 4AM and then another message between 4AM and 5AM? If I use your code and have one with 3 and 4 and another with 4 and 5 it displays both messages at the same time :)

Comment: Good job! :D Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
Set the flag true when its afternoon and later if the day is monday set the message as needed.

```
$afternoonFlag = False;
if ($current_time >= 12 && $current_time <= 16) {
    echo $afternoon;
    $afternoonFlag = True;
}
if ($current_day == "Monday" && $afternoonFlag) {
    echo "Your Message";
}
```